# wlst script to use parse several values to stop/start domains

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, wlst

I want to parse the following entries in config file:

```
[Domain1]
DOMAIN_NAME=my_domain1
NM_HOST=myhost1.com
ADMIN_URL=t3://myhost1.com:9001
DOMAIN_DIR=/nasn/app/oracle/admin/domains/mydomain_1/bin
WLS_DIR=/nasampn/app/oracle/product/fmw_api12c
ADMIN_USER=/software/wlst/secure/UPE/mydomain_1/AdminConfig.secure
ADMIN_PASS=/software/wlst/secure/UPE/mydomain_1/AdminKey.secure
NM_PORT=5556
NM_TYPE=SSL
OS_USER=oraamp

[Domain2]
DOMAIN_NAME=mydomain_2
NM_HOST=myhost1.com
ADMIN_URL=t3://myhost1.com:7001
DOMAIN_DIR=/nasn/app/oracle/admin/domains/mydomain_1/bin
WLS_DIR=/nasn/app/oracle/product/fmw_api12c
ADMIN_USER=/software/wlst/secure/UPE/mydomain_2/AdminConfig.secure
ADMIN_PASS=/software/wlst/secure/UPE/mydomain_2/AdminKey.secure
NM_PORT=5556
NM_TYPE=SSL
OS_USER=oraamp

[Domain3]
[Domain4,5,6,7]
```

for example and for each domain, I need to pass the values to connect to the admin server and stop and start the domain.

How can I parse the values so that I can provide the info for the connect and serverStart arguments

I am new python member and wanted to see why parser I can use to get this info

https://www.ebicus.com/en/blog/how-to-restart-managed-servers-simultaneously-with-wlst/

Comment: What do you mean by parsing??

Comment: @Anwarvic 

from configparser import ConfigParser

config_parser = ConfigParser()
config_parser.read('MyFile.conf')

for section_name in config_parser.sections():
   
    adminUrl=config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_URL')
    adminUser=config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_USER')
    adminPass=config_parser.get(section_name, 'ADMIN_PASS')
    connectAdmin(adminUrl,adminUser,adminPass)
    
def connectAdmin(adminUrl,adminUser,adminPass):
    print(adminUrl)
    print(adminUser)
    print(adminPass) ```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to install the `configparser` module in python. You can do that simply by opening the (command promp) on Windows or (terminal) on Linux, then write `pip install configparser` and your code should work perfectly!!